# My website wont connect to my databse Codeigniter on Namecheap {getaddrinfo Failed}

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, cpanel

I've uploaded my Codeigniter project via filezilla. My databse has been installed on Cpanel I've added a user with password and changed my config/database.php file.

which is here:

```
<pre>$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'http://mywebsite.space',
    'username' => 'myuser',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'database' => 'theNameOfMyDatabase',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => FALSE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array()
);

echo '<pre>';
  print_r($db['default']);
  echo '</pre>';

  echo 'Connecting to database: ' .$db['default']['database'];
  $dbh=mysql_connect
  (
    $db['default']['hostname'],
    $db['default']['username'],
    $db['default']['password'])
    or die('Cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db ($db['default']['database']);

    echo '<br />   Connected OK:'  ;
    die( 'file: ' .__FILE__ . ' Line: ' .__LINE__); 
</pre>`
```

The error I get when I navigate to my wesbite address:

```
<pre>
Cannot connect to the database because: 
php_network_getaddresses: 
getaddrinfo failed: 
Name or service not known
</pre>
```

I do have my codeigniter files in a folder off the root public_html folder.

public_html/myproject/
please help.

Comment: 'hostname' should probably be **localhost**

Comment: It worked! Thanks Dagon I needed localhost in there

Answer (score 0):

It's giving you the error because the url it's trying to reach probably doesn't exist. @Dagon is right, the `hostname` should be `localhost`.